# Error with strange symbols when I want to download a xls file from server

Tags: php, excel, download, xls

Hi I have this code to download a xls file from my server to my pc:

```
<?php

class ControllerDescExcel {

    public function getExcel() {

            $enlace = 'formatoexcel/formatoexcel.xls';
            header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$enlace ");
            header ("Content-Type: application/force-download");
            header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($enlace));
            readfile($enlace);                

    }

}

?>
```

But I have this error in my console :

[image]

Here is the xls file:

[image]

sorry by my english.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no output is generated by your script, except the readfile() contents.

I believe the filename may not contain path information. "file.xls" is OK, "path/file.xmls" is wrong.

Content-Type should be application/vnd.ms-excel

```
public function getExcel() {
    $enlace = 'formatoexcel/formatoexcel.xls';
    $file = basename($enlace); // only use file name not path
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');                  
    header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($enlace));
    readfile($enlace);
}
```

Comment: thank you I edited with your answer but still shows the same error :(